# Is $p(X \in A|\frac{Y+Z}{2}) = p(X \in A|Y,Z)?$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, information-theory

Let $X,Y, and \space Z$ be random variables. Let $A$ be a subset of $U$ such that $p(X \in U)=1$

Is $p(X \in A|\frac{Y+Z}{2}) = p(X \in A|Y,Z)?$

Do these two expressions represent the same thing? If so why is that true? Thank you!

Edit: Fixed notation according to Nicholas R. Peterson's tips

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Clearly, if you know $Y$ and $Z$, then you know their average; is the reverse true?

Try thinking about it in this light, and see if you can come up with an answer.  Let me know if you get stuck.

With that said, let me interject here that your notation is no good; are you intending $p$ to be a probability measure, or a density function?

If it is a probability measure, then this is meaningless: you can't compute the probability of a random variable... you need to compute the probability of an event.  So, it could be something like $P(X\in A\mid\frac{Y+Z}{2})$, etc.

Comment: The reverse is not true, can we therefore say that $X,Y$ gives us more information about $X$ than $ \frac{X+Y}{2} $? in other words, is $H(X|Y,Z) \leq H(X| \frac{X+Y}{2} ) ?$ Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Okay thank you for the tip about notation, I don't have a solid foundation in probability

Comment: How do I let you know if I get stuck haha do you get notifications when I reply to this:P?

Comment: It's a little bold to state that inequality -- that doesn't need to be true.  But your other point is exactly right -- knowing both $X$ and $Y$ gives you more information than just knowing their average.

Comment: Ouff sorry made a typo, what I wanted to write was $H(X|Y,Z) \leq H(X| \frac{Y+Z}{2})$? It has to be true haha..

Comment: What is $H$??? You're making claims about inequalities without defining what you actually mean.  That's why I said that it was "a little bold".

Comment: O haha sorry $H(X)$ is the entropy of the random variable X